# Would you use the term cucumber-time and why?

Tags: vocabulary, colloquialisms

During International Law studies I talked to English natives about politics, using a literal translation of the Dutch "komkommertijd", *cucumber time*, meaning to refer to the news-silent period of high summer. I thought they understood me.

Later it occurred to me that they might simply have nodded out of courtesy and may have missed the actual meaning. Looking it up, I found that *cucumber time* seems a dated term, out of use since more than a century.

Would you consider [*cucumber time*](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-cuc2.htm) and [*silly season*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silly_season) to be equivalent? Would you use either phrase or prefer one over the other?

Update: [this German text](http://mehrwisser.de/die-saure-gurken-zeit/) implies the English term is still in use, while [this Dutch text explicitly states](http://www.onzetaal.nl/taaladvies/advies/komkommertijd) the term is out of fashion and largely forgotten.

Comment: I was unaware of the phrase *cucumber time*, and would have been unable to define *silly season* either, before reading the links you give.  A common US term is *[dog days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_Days)*, typically referring to the hot weather of July and August.

Comment: Answered here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silly_season

Comment: @jwpat7: _dog days_ seems to refer to the hot weather (dog day afternoon), while these terms specifically refer to the lack of newsworthy items (etymology is shady, but it's generally accepted that the time that cucumbers are harvested is a slow time for business). Wikipedia comes up with _slow news season_ for Am. Eng, is that more familiar?

Comment: In the US we need this word. But really it should not be "cucumber time". It should be "pickletide".

Comment: @MetaEd: I already gave that link, what do you mean? It says nothing on the (potential) use of _cucumber time_ in modern day English. (edit: jkust saw your 2nd comment, lol)

Comment: @Abel: Of course it says nothing about "cucumber time". It says (correctly) that the American English term is "slow news season", and the British English term is "silly season". Having said so, it does not go on to list terms that are *not* used. ;-)

Comment: @MetaEd: Though this does: http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-cuc2.htm and this too http://mehrwisser.de/die-saure-gurken-zeit/. And sorry to say, but I can hardly consider Wikipedia a final and completely trustworthy evidence, not even when something is _not_ listed.

Comment: @Abel: _dog days_ can refer to a time hot weather, **or** to a period of inactivity; [see for yourself](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dog-days). To answer your other question, I'd never heard of _cucumber days_, either, so if you used it, you might have some explaining to do. I've also heard the expression "slow news day."

Comment: Although "[this German text](http://mehrwisser.de/die-saure-gurken-zeit/)" uses it, it doesn't mean that the literal translation is an English expression in common use.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: it reads _In England kennt man die Saure-Gurken-Zeit unter dem Namen „season of the very smallest potatoes“ oder auch „cucumbertime“ (Gurkenzeit)._. This means, literally: _In England they know the "Saure-Gurken-Zeit" by the term "season of the very smallest potatoes" and also as "cucumbertime"_. But it seems to me that the author got it wrong.

Comment: @jwpat7 By way of clarification, the "dog" in dog days originally referred to the dog constellation's position in the sky in the high summer, not to the lethargy of dogs in hot weather. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_Days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have answered your own question.

There does seem to be a period where real news appears to dry up and is replaced with more light-hearted material while the heavyweight correspondents are on holiday. In Britain this is universally known as the silly season. In fact I've never heard of "cucumber time".

Comment: Well, I was uncertain about it, and since so many languages have almost similar translations of "cucumber time", I figured it just _might_ be automatically understood still.